# How I can mock promises online for using in my pet project in Vue.js

Tags: api, vue.js, promise, mocking, frontend

Could I just import and enable some mocker in main.js of Vue.js project?
May it be after:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
```

?

How it can get started, anyway?
Thank you, in advance. Share your opinions.

Comment: Hi Ivan. Could you clarify what you want the "mocker" to do for your Vue application? For example, are you attempting to provide mock API data to your Vue application, or could you be mocking other components so that you can test your application in isolation?

Comment: I'm attempting to provide mock API data to whole Vue application, everywhere in different components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of great libraries already written that will intercept your API requests and return fake data.

The most complete libraries (in my opinion) that accomplish this goal are:

**Mirage.js** - you tell it which API returns what response, and external requests for data are routed to Mirage. I love this because this is very similar to the solution I built before Mirage was available, so it's a natural fit for me.

**JSON Server** - This runs as a server and returns your JSON files in response to API calls. This is cool because it simulates actual network traffic, even though it just loops back to localhost.

**Faker.js** looks like as the most complete library for generating fake data, so you may want to use it in conjunction with one of the above solutions, or if you replace your API calls with data requests to Faker, you can get around needing those other solutions.

There are a number of great articles on this technology. I loved reading Valentino Gagliardi's [4 ways to fake an API in frontend development](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/fake/) and LogRocket's [How to test code that depends on external APIs in Node.js](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-test-code-that-depends-on-external-apis-in-node-js/).